# Which features should be selected for my clustering analysis?

Tags: cluster-analysis, feature-selection

I want to cluster firms based on balance sheet data.

I have access to very detailed balance sheet data of firms. The dataset contains more that 1000 features for more than 1000 firms. Now, my goal is to cluster those firms with respect to their business model based on a subset of those features. Since I am interested in the business model of the firms I will scale the features by total assets. This should lower the predominant effect of the size of the firm on the clustering result.

In addition to some sort of analytical dimensionality reduction that I will perform, I also want to run the cluster analysis after intuitively reducing the number of features to use. Here, the nested nature of the features makes it hard for me to understand how the feature selection affects the clustering result. Let me explain.

Generally, I have three types of features (X, Y and Z) in the aggregated balance sheet. Features of type X have sub-variables x1, x2 and x3, that sum up to exactly X. Features of type Y have sub-variables y1 and y2 that sum up to less than Y, which means that there is some amount in Y that is not explicitely stated in the balance sheet or at least not stated in one of the immediate subordinate positions. Lastly, features of type Z do not have any sub-variables.

Here is an example balance sheet for depiction:

```
Assets          Liabilities
X (100)         A (200)
 x1 (30)          a1 (150)
 x2 (30)          a2 (25)
 x3 (40)          a3 (25)
x1+x2+x3=X         a1+a2+a3=A

Y (150)         B (200)
  y1 (10)          b1 (80)
  y2 (40)          b2 (100)

Z (350)         C (100)

Tot. Ass. (500) Tot. Liab. (500)
```

As long as I only include X, Y and Z (and A, B and C) in the cluster analysis I do not expect any problems.

Now, here is my series of questions:

1. Let's assume I want to include x1, x2 and x3 in the analysis. Should I exclude X? Moreover, do I run into trouble because of the magnitude of the numbers, which are now way smaller? I believe that using correlation based distance makes sense in this scenario. Do you agree?
2. Let's assume I want to include y1 and y2 into the analysis. In this case, I should not remove Y from the analysis, because depending on the size of y1 and y2 relative to Y, Y might still have a lot of explanatory power. Do you agree?

I would be thankful for any pointers and also just general advice on the clustering analysis/links to look at, etc.

P.s. I am doing the analysis in R.